# Login with a Google+ account

Tags: deezer

It seems like the Deezer android sdk doesn't provide Google+ authentication.

Is there a way for users connecting to Deezer with Google+ to access their account through the SDK?

Comment: For now, it's not possible to connect using the device's Google+ account. We're thinking about enhancing the login process in the SDK but nothing's done yet.

Comment: More and more users are complaining that they can't use my app because they can't login with their Google account. Any update on this ?

Comment: This would be very useful for my app too

Comment: 10 months have passed and this still seems to be an issue. To me this is a basic feature which needs to be implemented into the SDK.